# AD Group Policies NOT updating on client

Tags: active-directory

I have a test environment where I have an DC and 1 XP client on the same network.  I created a GPO and because of a syntax error, I removed it.  On the client, I have ran GPUPDATE /force several times and even restarted the client.  However, in the application event log, I see that the GPO is still being processed on the client (?? CACHED ??).  I don't understand how after I removed the GPO from AD, rebooted and forced another GPUPDATE on the client, the old policy still exists.  Is there any document on how to flush out the non-existent policy?

Thanks!

Comment: What policy did you apply, not all policies get removed with the GPO being unlinked

Comment: Did you run the gpupdate on the server? did you attempt to restart the server?

Answer (score 1):

Your first stop would be the event logs on the client, it will clearly log whether policies are being applied or not.

Answer (score 1):

On one of the test Domain Controllers, navigate to: C:\WINDOWS\SYSVOL\sysvol\\Policies
Locate the ghost GUID and delete.